Make Navigation Bar and Tab Bar not translucent in specific view
I have a super simple view like this:
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct Location: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack{
        Map()
            .navigationTitle("Posizioni")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
  }
}

This view is embedded in a TabView.
The result is the following:

I don't want the NavigationBar and the TabBar to be translucent in this view. The translucent effect is given by the Map that stretches under both of them. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? Thanks.

I feel foolish for not considering this solution earlier, but it works for me. Perhaps it will be helpful to others.:
NavigationStack{
        Map()
            .navigationTitle("Posizioni")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbarBackground(
                
                // 1
                Color("your_color"),
                // 2
                for: .navigationBar, .tabBar)
}

